# sscanf_s doesn't store the right pattern

Tags: c, scanf

I just want the string without underscore. I tried below few codes all doesn't work:

string is char pointer from another function, it looks like this: " "_I_have_1_dog.dat)" "

```
void func1(char *string)
{
char buffer[256]="";
unsigned long count = 0;
```

1. `count = sscanf_s(string, " \"%*c%255[^\"]\"", buffer, _countof(buffer));`

output:
_I_have_1_dog.dat

2. `count = sscanf_s(string, " \"%*[^_]_%255[^\"]\"", buffer, _countof(buffer));`

output:
_I_have_1_dog.dat

3. `count = sscanf_s(string, " \"[^_]_%255[^\"]\"", buffer, _countof(buffer));`

output:
_I_have_1_dog.dat

4. `count = sscanf_s(string, " \"[^_]_%255[^\"]\"", buffer, _countof(buffer));`

output:
_I_have_1_dog.dat

Comment: If you want to remove some characters from a string you read, then `scanf` (and it's family) is *not* the best choice. Read a "word" using (`scanf` or `scanf_s`) or a line (using `fgets`) and then "remove" the unwanted characters from the string.

Comment: So what is the expected result?

Comment: Expected result : I_have_1_dog.dat

Comment: @zxc6948 now please *[edit]* your question and add that

Comment: You can drop leading `_` with `%*[_]`. You had it *almost right*, but `%*[^_]` would drop *a continuous run of any other leading characters besides `_`!*

Answer (score 0):

**Edit Based on Removing 1st char `'_'` Instead of All `'_'`**

The easiest approach to remove a leading `'_'` is simply to shift all characters down by 1 in `string` if the first character is an `'_'`.

You can use the functions like `memmove` from `string.h` to do the same thing. (in a single function call) However, looping is just as easy.

A simple function using the loop method could be:

```
void rm_1st_underscore (char *string)
{
    int i = 1;      /* set index to 1 (2nd char in string) */

    if (*string != '_')             /* if 1st char not '_', just return */
        return;

    do                              /* loop over each char in string */
        string[i-1] = string[i];    /* shift chars back by 1 in string */
    while (string[i++] != 0);       /* (note: causes '\0' to copy) */
}
```

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rm_1st_underscore (char *string)
{
    int i = 1;      /* set index to 1 (2nd char in string) */

    if (*string != '_')             /* if 1st char not '_', just return */
        return;

    do                              /* loop over each char in string */
        string[i-1] = string[i];    /* shift chars back by 1 in string */
    while (string[i++] != 0);       /* (note: causes '\0' to copy) */
}

int main (void) {

    char str[] = "_I_have_1_dog.dat";

    rm_1st_underscore (str);

    puts (str);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rmunderscore
I_have_1_dog.dat
```

Look things over and let me know if you still have questions. If you need help trying it with `memmove` let me know and I'll drop another example.

**Using `memmove`**

Since we are just removing the first `'_'` instead of all of them, using `memmove` makes it trivial. Simply include `string.h` and get the length of `string` and then call `memmove` copying from the second char in `string` back to the first, e.g.

```
...
#include <string.h>

void rm_1st_underscore (char *string)
{
    size_t len = strlen (string);
    memmove (string, string + 1, len);
}
...
```

(the output is the same)

Comment: I am sorry, I just noticed I didn't put my problem statement clearly. I just want the string without the first underscore. So my expected output is: I_have_1_dog.dat

Comment: Oh brother.... I thought it was to remove the '_'. No problem. Simple fix hold on